# Logging for my Python TCP server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I need help for my Python TCP client code. I have a basic TCP client code now & I need to add logging features into so I can see the time & date of the sent data in a text file. A basic logging feature that is user friendly will do. Thanks alot for the help. I really appreciate it.

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 8888

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections
def clientthread(conn):
#Sending message to connected client
conn.send('Welcome to the server. Receving Data...\n') #send only takes string

#infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
while True:

    #Receiving from client
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    reply = 'Message Received at the server!\n'
    print data
    if not data:
        break

    conn.sendall(reply)

conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client



while 1:
#wait to accept a connection
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])``

#start new thread
start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. This is not a write-my-code-for-me website.

Comment: Sorry but you are in wrong place. Here is not [domyworkforme.com](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Logger module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html?highlight=logger) It should do what you need (but you'll have to read the doc and write the code yourself :P )